# Why YTS owner not jailed for illegal digital distribution, even police caught him?

Tags: internet, online-piracy

> **The guy behind YTS must be thanking his lucky stars.**

On 21 October, 2015 MPAA team shut down YTS site.

Mega Upload owner was jailed for decades, even after he is running legal site,
But YTS is not a legal site, but [here](https://torrentfreak.com/yts-strikes-mpaa-deal-but-dotcom-faces-decades-in-jail-151108/) torrentfreak site claims that he (referring to YTS owner) saved his own skin.

So why one get jailed & another doesn't?

Answer (score 6):

The probable answer is right there in the article: the Kim Dotcom case has been a PR coup but a legal disaster. Mr Dotcom has not, at this time, been jailed and it may have become apparent to US and NZ law enforcement agencies that he probably *never will be*!

It is really, really easy to accuse someone of committing a crime; it can be really, really hard to prove it beyond reasonable doubt in a court of law.

So after initiating a case that has turned out to be a total disaster, why would you expect them to do the same thing a second time?